# Split up R, G and B channels of texture – apply linear filtering to a subset of them in Three.js/WebGL/Shaders

Tags: three.js, shader, webgl, textures

I am working with a height texture that is retrieved from a server. It encodes the overall height value per pixel within the `RGB` channels. To get a height value per pixel, the `R` channel is multiplied by 65536.0, `G` with 256.0 , then `height = R + G + B`.

[image: RGB height texture]

Due to this splitting, `R` and `G` have discontinuities (see the image of the `G`channel below with the 100% white vs. 100% black areas) which they need since the other part (R or B) takes over. That's why I can't linearly filter the texture. I'd like, however, to linearly filter the `B` channel as it contains the highest frequencies/smallest height deviations – in order to get a smooth surface.

[image]

Is it possible to split up the texture internally (e.g., within the shader but I don't mind where this happens), so that only its `B` channel is linearly filtered while the `R, B` channels are left at nearest neighbour? Before all components are added together again? If so, how can this be done in an efficient manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebGL texture filtering applies to the whole texture, not each individual channel. But what you could do is [clone the texture](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/textures/Texture.clone), and sample them separately in the shader.

```js
var texture2 = texture1.clone();
texture1.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
texture2.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter; // This is the default
```

Then in your shader:

```glsl
vec2 sampleRG = texture2D(texture1, vUv).rg;
float sampleB = texture2D(texture2, vUv).b;
```

It's a little bit of extra overhead, but nothing your GPU can't handle.

Note, I've always seen each channel's value range from 0 to 255, not 256. Are you sure you don't want to multiply by 255 instead?

Comment: Cloning the texture and setting different `magFilters` makes perfect sense, thank you! In this case, multiplying with 256 is correct since the height values are distributed among the R, G and B channels — however, your remark regarding value range is also correct and helped me find another bug in my code. Thank you!